# How to set x and y Threshold line in C3 line graph

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

Using C3 graph for creating line graphs [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wa60afh9/) I need to add threshold line for a certain limit how do I add threshold line in c3 js.? I can able to add grid lines but how threshold line.Any Ideas

[image: Sample IMage]

Like the yellow highlighted line in the image.

```
c3.generate({
               size: {
                      height: 200,
                      width: 400 },
               data: {
                      json: colData,
                      type: 'spline'},
               grid : {
                        x:{
                           show:true},
                        y:{
                           show:true}
                      }
           });
```

coldata is

```
"coverage": {
      "Oc":[
        90,100, 115, 130, 145, 160, 160
      ],
      "Ce": [
        90,100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 180
      ],
      "Nl": [
        90,100, 130, 160, 190, 200, 200
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add additional grid lines using their [`xgrids.add`](http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-xgrids-add) or [`ygrids.add`](http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-ygrids-add) methods.

The methods add new x/y grid lines and can be passed a single object for one line or an array of objects for multiple lines.

I updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wa60afh9/2/

Comment: Yes I can able to get the xgrids and ygrids. Is there any other way to limit the x and y grids value to certain limit.? like the red line in my image.?

Comment: After some research, I didn't find any explicit way or method to set a threshold as you requested in your image. This is the closest solution I can find.